# Evaluating the limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{x(1 - 0.5\cos x) - 0.5\sin x}}{{{x^3}}}$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

For evaluating the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x(1 - 0.5\cos x) - 0.5\sin x}{x^3}$, I proceeded as follows:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x(1 - 0.5\cos x)}{x^3} - \frac{0.5}{x^2}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\right)$$

Using the fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \{ f(x) - g(x)\}  = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) - \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$, I got 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - 0.5\cos x}{x^2}  - \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{0.5}{x^2}$$
$$ = \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1 - 0.5\cos x - 0.5}{x^2} \right)$$

Now, after applying L'Hopital's Rule I got the final answer as $0.25$. However, on evaluating the original limit using Mathematica, I got the answer as $\frac{1}{3}$.

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong.

Somehow, I believe that you cannot use the fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \{ f(x) - g(x)\}  = \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) - \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$ in case of indeterminate forms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first problem is that you can't break up the limit like this.  In particular, you can only break up the limit into two limits when *both of the limits exist*.  Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{0.5}{x^2}$ does not exist (and neither does $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-0.5\cos(x)}{x^2}$), you would end up with $\infty-\infty$, which is indeterminate.

Comment: Hint: Just apply L'Hopital to the original expression, there is no need to break it up into smaller expressions (especially since that introduces an error).

Comment: Apply L'Hospital three times successively, and you get 2/6 which is 1/3.

Comment: Whoever writes the software used by those who use software to write MathJax code rather than writing MathJax code by hand must be having a competition to see who can make the code look more psychotic than anyone else's.  I cleaned this one up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compute this limit by making use of known basic limits then
use the following
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^{3}}=-\frac{1}{6},\ \ \ \ and\ \ \ \
\ \ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x(1-\frac{1}{2}\cos x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin x}{x^{3}}
&=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x(1-\frac{1}{2}\cos x)-\sin x}{%
x^{3}} \\
&=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2}\frac{x+x-x\cos x-\sin x}{x^{3}} \\
&=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}+\frac{%
1-\cos x}{x^{2}}\right)  \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}%
+\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}}\right)  \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\left( -\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\right) =\frac{1}{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Warning: When we write
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}+\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}}%
\right) =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}\right)
+\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}}\right) 
\end{equation*}
it is because we $\textbf{previously}$ know that the limits of the RHS exist
as real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use  *Taylor's development* at order $3$:

- $\cos x= 1-\dfrac{x^2}2+o(x^2)$, hence $\;x\bigl(1-\frac12\cos x\big)=\dfrac x2+\dfrac{x^3}4+o(x^3)$,
- $\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}6+o(x^3)$.

Thus the numerator is
$$\dfrac x2+\dfrac{x^3}4-\frac x2+\dfrac{x^3}{12}+o(x^3)=\dfrac{x^3}3+o(x^3)$$
and finally
$$\frac{x\bigl(1-\frac12\cos x\big)-\frac12\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{\dfrac{x^3}3+o(x^3)}{x^3}=\frac13+o(1)\to\frac13.$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply iteratedly l'Hôpital Rule to $$\frac{x(2-\cos x)-\sin x}{2x^3}$$ We get successively  $$\frac{2-2\cos x+x\sin x}{6x^2}$$  $$\frac{3\sin x+x\cos x}{12x}$$  $$\frac{3\cos x+\cos x-x\sin x}{12}$$

Thus the searched limit is the limit of $$\frac{4\cos x-x\sin x}{12}$$ when $x$ tends to $0$ which is clearly $\frac{4}{12}=\frac 13$

Comment: @Michael Hardy: My English is very weak (just for reading and zero for speaking) and I can not see what you have edited. Thanks anyway. You have a  very prestigious last name in mathematics (by G. H. Hardy)

Comment: If you write 3 sin x in MathJax, you see $3 sin x$, but if you write 3\sin x, with a backslash, you see $3\sin x$, with proper spacing before and after $\sin$ and with $\sin$ not italicized.  If you write $3\sin(x)$, coded as 3\sin(x), then you don't have the same amount of space after $\sin$ as when you write $3\sin x$.  My edit changed only some of the MathJax code. ${}\qquad{}$